# ansible 2.4 how to skip install of apt package if already installed with "with_item" loop and "when" condition

Tags: loops, ansible

```
i would like please to know if there is a way in a loop with_item.
```

to check and skip install of apt dependencies 
if already installed with "when" condition

```
if im adding the "when" condition in the end of the with_item list , its look like the condition check all the list instead of checking just the relevant - in this example python2 

- name: check if python already installed
  shell: dpkg-query -W python2.7
  register: check_python2
  ignore_errors: True


- name: Install apt dependencies
  apt:
    name: "{{item.name}}{{item.version}}"
    state: present
    allow_unauthenticated: yes
    force: yes
  with_items:
    - { name: 'python2.7', version: '' }
    - { name: 'ruby', version: '' }
    - { name: 'postgresql-9.5', version: '' }
    - { name: 'postgresql-contrib-9.5', version: '' }
    - { name: 'libpq-dev', version: '' }
    - { name: 'nodejs', version: '=9.*' }
    - { name: 'python-setuptools', version: '' }
    - { name: 'python-pip', version: '' }
    - { name: 'python-pkg-resources', version: '' }
    - { name: 'sshpass', version: '' }
    - { name: 'zip', version: '' }
    - { name: 'mongodb-org', version: '=4.0.0' }
    - { name: 'libfontconfig', version: '' }
    - { name: 'ntp', version: '' }
    - { name: 'fio', version: '' }
  when: check_python2.rc != 0
  when: check_ruby.rc != 0
```

how can i add the "when" condition to check only the right dependencies

i would like to check all the dependencies:

and if one of them not installed , install them otherwise skip

Comment: Why do you need to check if these packages are installed? If you just pass a list of packages to the apt module, just like if you invoked the apt command through a terminal, it will check and only install stuff that is not already installed. Be sure to pass the list of packages to the apt module 'name' param, as the module is optimized to deal with multiple packages at once.

Comment: thanks i know that , i just want to make it faster because when it check and pass with no change  it slower then when it "skip" the dependencies already installed.

Comment: i need to make the apt process more faster

Comment: Yes but in your example you are passing the list of packages as a loop.So apt gets run as many times as there items in your list - in your example, that is 15 times. Each time it needs to check dependency, etc. You can pass a simple list of package names or package_name=1.0.0 for a specific version to the name param of the apt module. This way, apt gets run once and will be much quicker. Read about the 'name' param in the docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand question, do you mean both conditions "check_python2.rc != 0" and "check_ruby.rc != 0" ?

```
when: check_python2.rc != 0 and check_ruby.rc != 0
```

Comment: figure it out - its much faster this why:

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: all:!
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    packages:
      - python2.7
      - ruby
      - postgresql-9.5
      - postgresql-contrib-9.5
      - libpq-dev
      - nodejs
      - python-setuptools
      - python-pip
      - python-pkg-resources
      - sshpass
      - zip
      - mongodb-org=4.0.0    
      - libfontconfig
      - ntp
      - fio

  tasks:
    - name: "Install dependencies"
      become: yes
      allow_unauthenticated: yes
      force: yes
      apt:
        pkg: "{{ packages }}"
        state: present
```